# How boost document with distinct content in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine, dismax

I have crawled a website with Apache Nutch and index it to Solr.every page of my website has same title, furthermore result found only in content field. then i can't boost fields like this:
content^0.5 title^2
Because my result is completely in content field.in every page exist a phrase in h2 html tag and i want to boost a document if the phrase(in h2 html tag) contain the word that searched for it.How i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Edismax](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) (extended [Dismax](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-DisMaxParameters)) Parser to boost the results according to the matches.
It allows to to boost matches based on individuals term matches (qf and qs), phrase matches with phrase slop (ps and ps) and shingle matches (pf2 and pf2).
You can configure the request handler to boost the matches accordingly for relevancy.